# drawing a pop-up with ShapeDrawable (Android)

Tags: android, dialog, popup, shapedrawable

I want to achieve something like this:
[image]

Is it possible with shapedrawable? how do I place the "triangle" part beneath the rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [Vector Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html). I guess it would be quite easy to achieve it with that. I can post the code here, but I think you should try yourself first and if you are not able to achieve it, paste your existing code :)

Comment: thanks.
Can it then be resized as 9-patch according to phone's res?

Comment: yes. That's good about vector drawables. Resizing is quite smooth.

Comment: ok thanks!
Just so I know in general, are there any more ways to achieve different graphical layout shapes like this in android?

Comment: Refer : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html.